# Как уберечься от зависания сервера из-за зацикливания алгоритма?

Tags: c#, .net, сервер, архитектура

Оказывается, небольшая ошибка, приводящая к зацикливанию кода, способна повесить не только целый сервис (в моём случае речь идёт о WCF), но и соседние сервисы, запущенные на том же сервере. Естественно, ситуация довольно печальная - всё приложение не работоспособно, поскольку сервер не отвечает на запросы. Что можно сделать, чтобы предотвратить такую ситуацию?

PS: [Подробнее об этом вопросе.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/9544/178988)

Comment: Наверное, вопросы, наверное,  глупые у меня, и все же.... С зависанием что случается на машине конкретно? Что с процессором? С памятью? Есть ли что интересного в дампе? Есть ли интересные ошибки или варнинги в логах операционной системы?

Comment: Я вот нашел линку, возможно, будет полезной: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/282756/intermittent-and-indefinite-wcf-hang-blocking-requ.html

Comment: @Andrew, вообще это довольно старая история, а я наконец-то добрался опубликовать по ней вопрос. Подробнее о истории можешь посмотреть по ссылке на мете. А на сам вопрос вроде можно много рассказать - от мониторинга нагрузки на процессор и потребления памяти до современной cloud-архитектуры. Может даже можно как-то тесты приплести.

Comment: Вообще я далек от этой темы... но, наверное, эта информация должна быть в самом вопросе. Вряд ли есть универсальный путь защищающий от всех подобных проблем и нужно разбиратся что случается в этом конкретном случае... И люди которые теоретически могут помочь должны иметь больше информации :)

Comment: @Andrew, на хабре целая статья была про прогу под линукс, которая следит за потреблением ресурсов и если что-то пошло не так, то что-нибудь прибивает и перезапускает. Причём это что-нибудь в первую очередь было СУБД - не помню точно, MySQL или Postgres. Так что проблема, видимо, не очень редкая.

Answer (score 0):

Можно сделать масштабируемое приложение. Несколько инстансов. Работают одновременно, либо рабочий+резервный. Мониторить, что отвечает на запросы, и перезапускать, если нет. Другие инстансы в это время отвечает на запросы.

Самый полный набор фишек на эту тему, пожалуй, у kubernetes. Но, чтоб всё это правильно настроить и адаптировать приложение, может пойти очень много времени.
Стоит заранее подумать, до какой степени оно реально надо.

Answer (score 0):

Вариант 1. Можно сделать аварийный кран. В случае, если алгоритм проходит сам себя определённое колличество раз, то процедура или функция автоматически завершалась.

Вариант 2. Найти проблемную зону и недопускать изначально таких зацикливаний

Вариант 3. Многопоточность.

Вариант 4. Масштабируемое приложение.